# В какой момент сущность пользователя становится отображением таблицы?

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate

[image: Связь]

Только начала использовать Hibernate и есть куча вопросов, на которые не могу найти ответов.  В какой момент сущность пользователя становится отображением таблицы? При загрузке? и собственно как это происходит?
Например, создается пустой объект, а поля заполняются данными из таблицы? В таком случае необходима ли инициализация полей коллекций до? 
Заранее спасибо=)

Comment: Рассматривая картинки вместо кода, у меня тоже обычно возникает много вопросов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы создать новую запись в БД, создаётся новый экземпляр класса `User`, заполняются его поля, затем объект передаётся в метод сохранения у `Hibernate`. `Hibernate` извлекает значения полей и формирует `SQL`-запрос вставки записи в таблицу (`INSERT`). Запрос выполняется, значения полей объекта обновляются (добавляется сгененрированный `ID` записи).

При чтении из БД существующих записей ситуация обратная: `Hibernate` осуществляет выборку из БД, создаёт сам экземпляр(-ы) класса `User`, заполняет поля и возвращает в ваш код уже готовые объекты.

Коллекции при создании новой записи следует инициализировать явно. При чтении же из БД коллекции инициализирует `Hibernate`. При этом, в случае отсутствия данных в коллекции возвращается пустая коллекция (а не `null`).